# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement'

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am currently trying to migrate a database from a 2003 .mdb to a 2007 .accdb, but I keep receving a syntax error. The first table of the database is called "_CustomerHistory" and is the only table with a special character. Here is the code I am currently working on:

```
        oldConnection.Open();

        DataTable schemaTable = oldConnection.GetSchema("Tables");

        foreach (DataRow schemaRow in schemaTable.Rows)
        {
            string tableName = schemaRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

            if (tableName.StartsWith("MSys"))
            {
                continue;
            }

            newConnection.Open();

            string createTable;

            if (tableName.StartsWith("_"))
            {
                createTable = $"CREATE TABLE [{tableName}] AS SELECT * FROM [{tableName}]";
            }
            else
            {
                createTable = $"CREATE TABLE {tableName} AS SELECT * FROM {tableName}";
            }

            OleDbCommand createTableCommand = new OleDbCommand(createTable, newConnection);
            createTableCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            newConnection.Close();
        }

        oldConnection.Close();
```

All help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: why do you have a select statement in the create statement?

Comment: I was attempting to select and copy everything from the _CustomerHistory table from the .mdb and create the same table, with the same information in the new .accdb, but I presume this is not the correct way to do this?

Comment: Any reason, why you do the conversion via code? You could do it manually, [see here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-a-database-to-the-accdb-file-format-098ddd31-5f84-4e89-8f44-db0cf7c11acd)

Comment: in the sql statement you want to create a table named {tablename} and then you select * from a table also named {tablename}. which makes no sense, either you create a table that already exists or you want to read something from a table that doesnt exist. you need a sql statement to the old db to read the table name and then a seperate sql statement to the new db to create the table name.